# turkee: undefined method `reverse_merge!' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanicalturk

In trying to get [turkee](https://github.com/aantix/turkee) working, I'm getting an `undefined method`reverse_merge!' for nil:NilClass` error.

My Code:

```
class MechanicalTurksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @mechanical_turk = MechanicalTurk.new
    @disabled = Turkee::TurkeeFormHelper::disable_form_fields?(params)
  end
end

<%= turkee_form_for(@mechanical_turk, params) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, disabled: @disabled %>

    <br />
    <%= f.submit "Save", class:"btn btn-primary", disabled: @disabled %>
<% end %>

class MechanicalTurk < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I think the problem is the `params` hash.  I think it's missing something.  The documentation says

> Mechanical Turk is now requiring that the hitId, workerId, and the
>   turkSubmitTo parameters be passed in along with the assignmentId and
>   form parameters.

Here's the output from my logs:

```
Started GET "/mechanical_turks/new?assignmentId=ASSIGNMENT_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE&hitId=2Z2MN9U8P9Y3B78UW1US1YIM5R7VEG" for 208.54.40.228 at 2012-05-08 17:35:24 -0400
Processing by MechanicalTurksController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"assignmentId"=>"ASSIGNMENT_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE", "hitId"=>"2Z2MN9U8P9Y3B78UW1US1YIM5R7VEG"}
  Rendered mechanical_turks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `reverse_merge!' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <%= turkee_form_for(@mechanical_turk, params) do |f| %>
    2:     <%= f.label :first_name %>
    3:     <%= f.text_field :first_name, disabled: @disabled %>
    4: 
  app/views/mechanical_turks/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_mechanical_turks_new_html_erb___897197135_79286580'
```

I've also posted an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/aantix/turkee/issues/12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used most recent release from github and it works now.